# What is the new segwit network option on binance and how does it work?

Tags: segregated-witness, binance

Recently Binance announced support for segwit deposits. I see old address and lot of other options on the right with segwit in the end. Is it a new network? What are the other options mentioned on Binance to deposit BTC and are they similar to segwit?
[image: binance-deposit]

Comment: Other questions on this site answer what is SegWit and the benefits of SegWit. I don't see why Binance specifically is brought into this. So that's three of the four questions that should be closed if looked at individually. I'd be open to a question on what wallets support SegWit although given that it changes all the time the information would quickly become stale without regular updates. Hence voting to close.

Comment: Closing doesn't help anything. Thanks for your contribution. I was expecting considering your votes on my questions in past and one of the reasons I post less questions and more answers here.

Comment: Hmm a touch bizarre response. I've reached out to you privately.

Comment: Please make your question more focused. There are 4 questions here, and some of them already have good answers in this site.

Comment: I have edited the Question. Hope this looks better. I obviously know the answers to all and thats why answered it myself but intention was to share the misleading options available there to deposit BTC and how segwit is mentioned as a separate network. I mentioned all questions a newbie would have if looking at such option for the first time.

Comment: User: How do I send BTC to 0x address?https://i.ibb.co/0fr5m2K/Screenshot-20201228-042037-01-01.jpg Binance Support: Sir BTC fees are high so this is new network with low fees. Change to some wrapped token and use it.

Comment: Not sure if you realize or not this affects **Bitcoin** and **Segwit adoption**

Answer (score 2):

On 2020-12-24, Binance announced support for deposits to native segwit addresses.

Segregated witness ("segwit") refers to a soft fork that activated a series of Bitcoin improvement proposals (BIPs) in 2017. Among other things, segwit introduced two new standard output types, Pay to Witness Public Key Hash (P2WPKH) and Pay to Witness Script Hash (P2WSH). These *native segwit outputs* are more blockweight efficient than prior equivalent output formats, but wallets had to be updated to create them.

After three years, receiving payments to native segwit addresses is considered best practice, and almost all wallets and services are [able to send](https://bitcoinops.org/en/compatibility/#segwit-addresses) to native segwit addresses.

Answer (score 1):

1. Segwit is **not a separate network** as mentioned in the screenshot instead its a Bitcoin protocol upgrade that provides lower transaction fees. This is also mentioned in the "Tips" section on same page in Binance.
2. Segwit is defined in [BIP](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips): 141,143,144,145 and 173 according to my understanding. In this context its just an address type you will use for BTC deposits on Binance.
3. Most of the open source and self-custodial wallets support segwit. Example: Bitcoin Core, Electrum, Samourai, Wasabi, Bluewallet etc.
4. Other things mentioned to deposit BTC: **BEP2, BEP20 (BSC) and ERC20 are not associated with Bitcoin**. It is **misleading** and you will need tokens on other chains to deposit using those addresses which is not same as bitcoin.
5. You can read about benefits of segwit here: https://bitcoincore.org/en/2016/01/26/segwit-benefits/