# Moving BTC to cold wallet over Binance

Tags: transaction-fees, withdrawal, binance, binance-coin

The BTC withdrawal fee in Binance (and pretty much every other exchange) is 0.0005 BTC - very high. However, if you do the withdrawal over their Binance network then the fee is only 0.0000014 BTC (a mere fraction!). Question is, can that network be used to withdraw "pure" BTC? How? The address I have on my (Trezor) cold wallet is a SegWit address which apparently doesn't fit the criteria.

Also, if it's stored in a separate network, does that mean that I'll only be able to sell my BTC via Binance?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> However, if you do the withdrawal over their Binance network then the fee is only 0.0000014 BTC (a mere fraction!)

This transaction will involve withdrawal of a token on other chain. This token is not same as BTC. I have explained few things in this answer: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/100838/

Those options available for BTC withdrawal are misleading but there is nothing much we can do about it. I tried my best by creating a question on Stackexchange, sharing on Reddit and ask few people to tweet about it. Not sure what else can be done for the misinformation, marketing, misleading things etc. by altcoiners in this ecosystem.

Comment: How do you empirically know that misinformation and misleading things are being spread specifically by altcoiners?

Comment: Because I am not a newbie. Involved in Bitcoin since 2015, was founder of [flybit](https://archive.factordaily.com/flybit-cheap-air-tickets-bitcoins/) in 2017 and active on Stackexchange since last year. It's not difficult to understand how marketing works. In this case everyone knows background of CZ, involvement of Binance in different things and other misinformation being shared regularly by people involved in altcoins.

Comment: I think your comments are quite broad and may be slightly unfounded without empirical evidence, it's anecdotal. I personally don't know about the background of CZ nor what this has to do with altcoins either.

Comment: Ignore the things that you don't understand or not agree with. Your question is answered : those tokens are on different chain and not same as BTC.

Comment: Okay, but what do altcoiners have to do with this, is my question. I’m not the OP

Comment: @Prayank: You are not speaking with the asker but a third party. I for one agree with Hamish Gibson though. Your answer would have a higher quality if it focused on answering the question factually. It is diminished by the opinionated allegations needlessly.

Comment: Okay I didn't check the name of user who asked the question and user who commented. Sorry for the confusion. As far as answer is concerned, it has addressed the things OP was looking for. I have added my opinions based on https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/100837/what-is-the-new-segwit-network-option-on-binance-and-how-does-it-work/ , https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/101628/comparing-utxo-transactions-with-accounts-transactions , Binance's involvement in crypto, tweets from CZ and so many other things. You can edit my answer but its all related and my thoughts about things.

Comment: @Prayank I appreciate your answer a lot, it's on point and it explicitly states you're given another token rather than a BTC as I asked. While your second part of the comment might be an opinion that doesn't apply to all altcoins it is definitely valid. Binance's website is empirical. Saying you can withdraw BTC over a network other than BTC's is misinformation. And this misinformation is provided by Binance in regards to their altcoin. So yeah that's pretty much empirical proof of your statement.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me that the differing fees stem from a qualitative difference in what you are being offered. The "withdrawal over the Binance network" provides you an IOU for Bitcoin. If you want to take possession of the actual bitcoins on your Trezor, you will need to chose the Bitcoin withdrawal method. This is more expensive, because it requires an on-chain transaction to be committed to the Bitcoin blockchain.